# A simple way of telling the frontend whether or not an Entity is finished updating?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an API that updates an entity (called Document) inside a SQL database. This update can sometimes take a few minutes. I also have an Angular Frontend that lets the user select a document and edit it. I want to stop the user from selecting a Document that is still in the process of updating. If the user can’t select the document from the frontend, it is impossible to update the document.

In order to accomplish this goal, I added a column called locked in the document to table to indicate whether a document should be selectable. (If locked is true, the frontend will stop the user from selecting the document.) Before running the async method to update the document, I set locked to true. The async method will then set locked equal to false when it is done updating the document. If something goes wrong inside the async method, I will also set locked back to false.

Here is the code:

DocumentAPI:

```
@PostMapping("/updateDocument")
public ResponseEntity<Document> updateDocument(@RequestBody Document document) {
    this.documentService.lockDocument(document);
    this.documentService.updateDocumentAsync(document);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Document(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

DocumentService:

```
@Transactional
@Async
public void updateDocumentAsync(Document document){
    try{
        //a bunch of computation
        document.setLocked(false);
        documentRepo.save(document);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        document.setLocked(false);
        documentRepo.save(document);
    }
}

public void lockDocument (Document document){
    document.setLocked(true);
    documentRepo.save(document);

}
```

Is this approach suitable enough for my needs (making sure the user can’t select the document on the frontend), or should I use the Pessimistic/Optimistic locking mechanisms supported by the Spring JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to be simple so to speak.

In a high concurrency system with async writes you might need both the flag as well as to use pessimistic locking.  The way you have it now its certainly possible that someone else is reading the row while you are in the process of writing the locked value.  That being the case you will want some version of pessimistic reading/writing around your db transaction specifically around the setting of the row flag.

Answer (score 0):

`repo.save()` returns null if unsuccessful and not null if successful. Seems you are trying to save in both function instead in only one. Try the following snippet

```
public void lockDocument (Document document){
 try {
   document.setLocked(true);
   document = documentRepo.save(document);
   if(document != null) {
     document.setLocked(false);
   }
 } catch(Exception e) {
    document.setLocked(false);
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```